# Element not located at bottom of viewport

Tags: html, css, anchor, viewport

So I am trying to do an menu for the viewer to easily access specific chapters of a long webpage.
I use anchor tags that links to different sections using ID's. But when I click the links from my menu the sections are located at the bottom of the viewport. On the other hand - if I try to access the section using the full URL the view port goes (as intended) to the top of the viewport.

What is up with the links from my menu - why are they not working?

https://learningbank.io/employee-journey/#cap03

Comment: the link you share need credentials

Comment: check your url , need credentials

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Authorization is required for your link

Comment: So sorry - the credentials are removed as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the original code.

In any case, you may have set the anchors to high so when you click the link it sends you somewhere higher then where you intended.

Otherwise. You could always add more pages and have them as `<link href="">` links. Thats if you have no other solution though.

Comment: I don't think the anchor are placed wrongly 'cause when I load the url with the id number of the section, the page scrolls nicely to the right position. So it is only when I use the menu links the offset is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Or rather the Wordpress builder (Elementor) I use for making the website actually comes with an widget that handles anchor links. It seems the builder itself interferes with the regular practice of adding links.